# Python Scripting Question

Tags: python, scripting

I have a question about writing a small tool that would provide the headers for any website. I am new to python but wanted to know if there is anything else other than encoding that I would have to account for in my code when developing the tool? I have a rough draft of my code shown below. Any pointers from the python coders?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, urllib


if len(sys.argv) == 2:
  website = sys.argv[1]
website = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1])
if(website.code != 200): 
  print "Something went wrong here"
  print website.code 
  exit(0)

print 'Printing the headers'
print '-----------------------------------------'
for header, value in website.headers.items() :
    print header + ' : ' + value
```

Comment: What does this have to do with security? Also, why not just use curl?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a fairly straightforward script (though this question seems more of a fit for stackoverflow).  Couple comments, first `curl -I` is a useful command line tool to compare against.  Second, even when you don't get 200 status, there are still often useful content or headers you may want to display.  E.g.,

```
$ curl -I http://security.stackexchange.com/asdf
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 24068
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: prov=678b5b9c-0130-4398-9834-673475961dc6; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:24:00 GMT
```

Also note `urllib` follows redirects automatically.  E.g., with curl you'll see:

```
$ curl -I http://www.security.stackexchange.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 157
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://security.stackexchange.com/
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:26:52 GMT
```

while your tool will just give.

```
$ python user3567119.py http://www.security.stackexchange.com
Printing the headers
-----------------------------------------
content-length : 68639
set-cookie : prov=9bf4f3d4-e3ae-4161-8e34-9aaa83f0aa4b; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
expires : Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:29:32 GMT
vary : *
last-modified : Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:28:32 GMT
connection : close
cache-control : public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
date : Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:28:31 GMT
x-frame-options : SAMEORIGIN
content-type : text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Third, if you continue playing around with HTTP requests in python, I highly recommend using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).  With requests, you'll be able to see the 301 if you do:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r=requests.get('http://www.security.stackexchange.com')

In [3]: r
Out[3]: <Response [200]>

In [4]: r.history
Out[4]: (<Response [301]>,)
```

It's also worth trying out some HTTP requests in just plain old telnet.  E.g., `telnet security.stackexchange.com 80` then quickly type:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: security.stackexchange.com
```

followed by a blank line.  Then you'll see the actual HTTP response on the wire (instead of recreating it after urllib has processed the HTTP response):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:38:37 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:37:37 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: prov=a75de1f2-678b-4a9d-bbfd-39e933e60237; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 25 Apr 2014 07:37:36 GMT
Content-Length: 68849

<!DOCTYPE html>
```